# AstroJS - process is undefined for process.env with dotenv package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments, production-environment, astrojs

I tried to load a secret from .env file which is stripe publishable key

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()
```

while importing this I'm getting the error as

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: process is not defined
```

I'm currently using astrojs framework where I've been using `import.meta.env` but that doesn't seem to work in production build where I have setup the key value in docker-compose file and I couldn't see the value. It's `undefined`. Either solving with docker-compose with `import.meta.env` or resolving dotenv would be fine. What will suit the best if we store stripe publishable key?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how you run your code in production. If you run your code with server side rendering in node environment you can use process.env

If you are in doubt look in the file astro.config.mjs

Here is an example from [the documentation](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/integrations-guide/node/) using a node adapter and server side rendering:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config';
import node from '@astrojs/node';

export default defineConfig({
  output: 'server',
  adapter: node({
    mode: 'standalone'
  }),
});
```

If your astro.config.mjs looks like this you might get your env variables in the following way:

```
const value = import.meta.env.PUBLIC_VALUE ?? process.env.PUBLIC_VALUE
```

The above strategy prioritises getting the values through import.meta.env if set. But uses process.env if it's not defined.

For me this strategy works both when running my code locally and through docker.

Its important that the variable name starts with `PUBLIC_`  This is because only `PUBLIC_` variables are available server side, as mentioned [here](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/environment-variables/)